# Is j2me nokia API is working with other mobile or not?

Tags: api, java-me, nokia

I'm developing mobile application in j2me. My target phone is "Nokia". In my app I'm using some Nokia API's .Now the requirements change, so that many other target devices than Nokia are also included. Here my doubt is if, on other phones, the mobile app developed with Nokia API is working or not. Please share your ideas.

Comment: You'll probably get better help if you include in your question what other phones are targeted.

Comment: my other phones are "sony ericsson","samsung" etc

Comment: Can you please list the Nokia APIs that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work, you might get ClassNotFoundException after running the midlet on different devices. Nokia UI library will residing be in Nokia mobile OS.

I haven't tried but if you can add the Nokia UI jar in your project as library and then try it on other devices. I will also try it. But i guess some of the api's will be having hardware dependency like sound etc..